# OpenCV Rectification with too much black areas on images C++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, calibration

I'm using OpenCV to calibrate and rectify a stereo system. I have a stereo camera with convergent eyes, actually I'm running these functions on this order:

```
for(int j=0; j < ChessBoard.numSquares; j++)
    obj.push_back(Point3f((j/ChessBoard.numCornersHor)*ChessBoard.squareDim, (j%ChessBoard.numCornersHor)*ChessBoard.squareDim, 0.0f));
[...]
```

Then I loop this for the numbers of the images that I would like to acquire

```
found_L = findChessboardCorners(image_L, ChessBoard.board_sz, corners_L, CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS + CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
found_R= findChessboardCorners(image_R, ChessBoard.board_sz, corners_R, CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS + CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
found = found_L && found_R;
if(found)
  { 
    cornerSubPix(image_L, corners_L, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
    cornerSubPix(image_R, corners_R, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
    drawChessboardCorners(image_L, ChessBoard.board_sz, corners_L, found);
    drawChessboardCorners(image_R, ChessBoard.board_sz, corners_R, found);

    image_points[0].push_back(corners_L);
    image_points[1].push_back(corners_R);
    object_points.push_back(obj);
    printf("Right: coordinates stored\n");
    printf("Left: coordinates stored\n");
  }
```

After this block I call this two:

```
cameraMatrix[0] = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
cameraMatrix[1] = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);

calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points[0], imageSize, cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0], rvecs_L, tvecs_L);

calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points[1], imageSize, cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1], rvecs_R, tvecs_R);
```

and then:

```
rms = stereoCalibrate(object_points, image_points[0], image_points[1],
                    cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0],
                    cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1],
                    imageSize, R, T, E, F,
                    TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
                    CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO+CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC);
```

finally:

```
stereoRectify(cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0],
                  cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1],
                  imageSize, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q,
                  CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, -1, imageSize, &roi1, &roi2 );

initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0], R1, P1, imageSize, CV_16SC2, map11, map12);
initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1], R2, P2, imageSize, CV_16SC2, map21, map22);
remap(imgL, imgL, map11, map12, INTER_LINEAR,BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());
remap(imgR, imgR, map21, map22, INTER_LINEAR,BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());
```

This is basically what I'm doing, but the result is really bad, because the images have a really big black area. Here is an example:

[image: Left From OpenCV]

and this is the rectify image that I have to obtain, that is taken rectified directly from the camera:

[image: Left From Camera]

As you can see it seems that the image is translated on the right side and cut, with the right one is the same but is translated on the left side and the result is nearly the same.

So how can I achieve a better result similar to the last one? Where is the problem? 
As an additional data  I have noticed that rms is not so good, about 0.4, and the re-projection error is about 0.2, I know that they must me a bit lower, but I have try many many times with different pattern, illumination and so on, in calibration but I always take the same result or even worst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `stereoRectify` like this:

```
stereoRectify(cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0],
              cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1],
              imageSize, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q,
              0, -1, imageSize, &roi1, &roi2 );
```

i.e. use `0`instead of the flag `CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY`.

Also, in order to improve the RMS obtained by `stereoCalibrate`, try with flag `CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS` (see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059076/stereocalibrate-changes-focal-lengths-even-when-it-was-not-supposed-to/23082274#23082274)):

```
rms = stereoCalibrate(object_points, image_points[0], image_points[1],
                cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0],
                cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1],
                imageSize, R, T, E, F,
                TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
                CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS+
                    CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO+CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC);
```

Comment: This fixed the main problem and I see a good disparity map, but now the Q matrix, that I use for the reprojectImageTo3D is really bad. I use the result for distance calculation and see the 3D reconstruct in a visualizer, but now is not even close to the truth like before. So the Q matrix is not well calculated in that way. Why?

Comment: @Elminster_cs Finding out why the result of `reprojectImageTo3D` is bad would require additionnal data. Can you ask a new question on that topic and include the appropriate code (call to `reprojectImageTo3D`, etc) & pictures? Post the link to that new question here, as a comment, so this stays linked to this question. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with the reproject was a simple conversion: I was using a disptype==CV_16S and I was needing a 32F. So i just put:
disp.convertTo( disp16, CV_32F, 1./16); and now is working, thanks!